# Overflow hidden not working on Android

Tags: android, css, cordova

I have a picture displaying in  a DD which has rounded corners. When I build it and get it on an android device the overflow:hidden doesn't work and the full picture shows over the dd. Anyone else have this issue and know a workaround/fix?

This is the CSS for the DD.

```
.empImage {
    position:absolute;
    width:90px;
    height:110px;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border: #f26122 solid thin;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px #666;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px #666;
}
```

Comment: Put img tag inside div{overflow:hidden;}.

Comment: div, dd, section, none of them work.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Had to wrap the image in 2 divs/sections/dd and put overflow:hidden on the inner one. In this case the section.

Before(didnt work)

```
<dd><img></dd>
```

Now(works)

```
<dd><section><img></section></dd>
```

Comment: Try to validate your code [http://validator.w3.org/] and you will get markup error

Answer (score 14):

Overflow:hidden doesn't work on android when the element is relative or absolute position.

The simplest workaround is to have an outer element with relative/absolute and an inner element with the overflow.

```
<div style="position:absolute">
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden">
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!